# Adding items to ListView repeats same XML element

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a listView box and I'm adding items into it. But it's giving me the same text/item for the idAtt and applicIDAtt elements in every row. The desc does update to a new value for every row.

Code

```
Public Sub loadFile()
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(fileName)
    Dim LItem As New ListViewItem

    For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure/faultDescr/descr")
        Dim idAtt = node.SelectSingleNode("//faultIsolationProcedure/@id").InnerText
        Dim desc As String = node.InnerText
        Dim applicIDAtt = node.SelectSingleNode("/dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure/@applicRefId").InnerText

        Dim lv As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(idAtt)
        lv.SubItems.Add(desc)
        lv.SubItems.Add(applicIDAtt)
    Next
End Sub
```

Example XML

```
<dmodule>
<content>
    <faultIsolation>
        <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId="Software" id="tree1">
            <fault faultCode=" "/>
            <faultDescr>
                <descr>This nodes description</descr>
            </faultDescr>
        </faultIsolationProcedure>
    </faultIsolation>
</content>
```

Comment: Screenshot please, and a sample dump of your XML file

Comment: I've added the sample XML, I couldn't find anywhere I could attach an image of the form. @Caius Jard

Comment: To post screenshots, use Windows snipping tool to take the shot, press ctrl c, come to SO, press ctrl v when in the text editor for the question body. SO will upload the clipboard to imgur and insert a link into the body text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpaths are a bit wonky; you're not really treating the document like a set of hierarchical nodes. If it helps, think of it like file paths and folders. Get the "folder" at a particular path and pull out its attributes/innertexts (files) but address it relatively from where you are

```
For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure")
    Dim idAtt = node.Attributes("id").Value
    Dim desc As String = node.SelectSingleNode("faultDescr/descr").InnerText
    Dim applicIDAtt = node.Attributes("applicRefId").Value
```

Now, you didn't really post a usefully large XML document sample for me to work out exactly at what hierarchy level the nodes repeat themselves, so I assumed it's like this:

```
<dmodule> 
    <content>
        <faultIsolation>
            <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId=""Software"" id=""tree1"">
                <fault faultCode="" ""/>
                <faultDescr>
                    <descr>This nodes description</descr>
                </faultDescr>
            </faultIsolationProcedure>

            <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId=""Software2"" id=""tree2"">
                <fault faultCode="" ""/>
                <faultDescr>
                    <descr>This nodes description2</descr>
                </faultDescr>
            </faultIsolationProcedure>
        </faultIsolation>
    </content>
</dmodule>
```

1 `faultIsolation` node has multiple `faultIsolationprocedure` nodes

Here's a complete code you can paste into some vb.net fiddle site and run to highlight the problem. Read the full code, including my comments. I put my code above and then your code, with a commentary on each, in comments in the VB:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml

Public Module Module1



    Public Sub Main()

        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.LoadXml("<dmodule> 
    <content>
        <faultIsolation>
            <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId=""Software"" id=""tree1"">
                <fault faultCode="" ""/>
                <faultDescr>
                    <descr>This nodes description</descr>
                </faultDescr>
            </faultIsolationProcedure>

            <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId=""Software2"" id=""tree2"">
                <fault faultCode="" ""/>
                <faultDescr>
                    <descr>This nodes description2</descr>
                </faultDescr>
            </faultIsolationProcedure>
        </faultIsolation>
    </content>
</dmodule>")

        '#####################################
        '                 my way
        '#####################################

        'treat /dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure as a collection of nodes, do each one
        For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure")

            'pull attribute by name
            Dim idAtt = node.Attributes("id").Value

            'pull a sub node relative to the current node, not the document root
            Dim desc As String = node.SelectSingleNode("faultDescr/descr").InnerText

            'pull attribute by name
            Dim applicIDAtt = node.Attributes("applicRefId").Value

            Console.WriteLine(idAtt)
            Console.WriteLine(desc)
            Console.WriteLine(applicIDAtt)

        Next

        Console.WriteLine("##############")

        '#####################################
        '              your way
        '#####################################
        For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure/faultDescr/descr")

            'well it sort of works for the first one, because // is always the document root
            'in xpath, not the current node. The node you're looking at still knows of the
            'document and if you ask it to search for an xpath starting with // you're NOT
            'searching from the current node as a start point, but the doc root. this is why
            'you keep getting the same node, because the code goes back to the doc root and
            'pulls the first child node, which is always the same node!
            Dim idAtt = node.SelectSingleNode("//faultIsolationProcedure/@id").InnerText

            'this is OK - it works relative to the node you're currently on in the foreach
            'and it does return different descriptions each time
            Dim desc As String = node.InnerText

            'Again, this xpath starts with / which is "from the doc root" not "from the current node"
            '-because this doesn't have a double slash it has to be an exact path from the doc root
            'which is IS - it's a valid path and it might well be that there are lots of nodes
            'in the document with this path, but your call to selectsinglenode will only
            'give you the first encountered node in the document, so its always the same node..
            Dim applicIDAtt = node.SelectSingleNode("/dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure/@applicRefId").InnerText
            Console.WriteLine(idAtt)
            Console.WriteLine(desc)
            Console.WriteLine(applicIDAtt)

        Next
    End Sub



End Module
```

Remember. If you have a file system like this:

```
c:\temp\my\path\file.txt
```

You can do this:

```
CD c:\temp\my
```

And you'll be in the `my` folder, and you can either refer to the file relatively or absolutely:

```
notepad path\file.txt
notepad c:\temp\my\path\file.txt
```

XPath is no different; if you start a path with a slash it's "from the doc root" no matter what the current node is, just like if you start a file path with `c:\` it's from the drive root, no matter what the current directory is

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This worked great!

Comment: @JenPann The correct way to thank people on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer. You do this by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: @jenPenn (And you can also click the up arrow. An answer can be both ticked and upvoted. Any number of helpful answers can be upvoted but only one (that best applies to your situation) can be ticked)